# There exist a Graph API query that is related to me when a user makes a call (audio), or desktop sharing, through Microsoft-Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I specify that what is mentioned here https:[Calls and Online meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calls-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) does not help me because you have to create a bot and invite him to the conversation which does not interest me

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Detect when _any_ call is initiated or desktop is shared? What's the use case you're trying to enable?

Comment: For example, if Bob calls Alice or shares her desktop I'll be interested in detecting that via the graph. As is possible for chat conversations using the query users/{userId}/messages

Comment: Nothing like this currently exists in the Graph APIs that are available today. I do understand from the comments above the capability you are looking for. Can you elaborate a bit more on the end-to-end scenario you are interested in enabling?